# creating wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, dreamweaver

I need to create a fresh wordpress template using adobe dreamweaver .  I want the template with image slider , stylish menus and commenting options. please guide me from basic to end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll find this tutorial helpful:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/dw-wordpress-multiscreentheme.html

as well as this:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/dw_wordpress_pt1.html

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress Template starts with

```
<?php /* Template Name: Stylish Template */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?> // go to header.php add required js file for slider & menu through wordpress function() <?php wp_nav_menu($args); //check wordpress documentation for $args.
<div id="slider">
--images will go here
</div>
<div id="content">--Content Goes here---These will be posts from any category or latest posts, look wordpress documentation for <?php comment_template() to add comments if they are disabled.?></div>
```